# How do I find the answer number in a post?

Tags: support

I've seen pages like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time-experimental-challenge) where they have links to answers in the description. I've noticed this works by adding a number to the end of the URL (i.e, 12345). How do I find this number so I can link things? (I know how to do it for my answers, but I'm wondering about answers in general.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the very bottom of the answer, on the left side, you will see a small "share" button. Clicking this will display a URL that links directly the answer.  This URL will contain the answer's ID number, followed by *your* user ID number.

Comment: Specifically, the first number is the post ID, and the second is your user ID (used for tracking the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges).

Comment: @Doorknob edited :)

Comment: @Doorknob Interesting.  So http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4993/11259 and http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4993/3808 and http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4993/2867 all point to this answer, but boost those badge stats for me, you and PhiNotPi respectively?

Comment: @MariaTidalTug Correct. (However, those links as you've posted them here specifically won't increment the badge stat, because links from within Stack Exchange don't count for those badges.)

Comment: @Doorknob That's not true. You can get bronze and silver from internal links. Only gold disregards them. (That's why some people got Announcer's for PhiNotPi's Unscrambling challenge, due to the cross references between the cops and robbers thread.)